# How can I return a record from a CSV file using the byte position of line?

Tags: csv, rust, offset

I have an `assets.csv` file with 172 MB, a million rows, and 16 columns. I would like to read it using an `offset -> bytes/line/record`. In the code below, I am using the byte value.

I have stored the required positions (`record.postion.bytes()` in `assets_index.csv`) and I would like to read a particular line in the `assets.csv` using the saved offset.

I am able to get an output, but I feel there must be a better way to read from a `CSV` file based on byte position.

Please advise. I am new to programming and also to Rust, and learned a lot using the tutorials.

The `assets.csv` is of this format:

```
asset_id,year,depreciation,year,depreciation,year,depreciation,year,depreciation,year,depreciation,year,depreciation,year,depreciation,year,depreciation,year,depreciation,year,depreciation,year,depreciation,year,depreciation,year,depreciation,year,depreciation,year,depreciation
1000001,2015,10000,2016,10000,2017,10000,2018,10000,2019,10000,2020,10000,2021,10000,2022,10000,2023,10000,2024,10000,2025,10000,2026,10000,2027,10000,2028,10000,2029,10000
```

I used another function to get the `Position { byte: 172999933, line: 1000000, record: 999999 }`.

The `assets_index.csv` is of this format:

```
asset_id,offset_inbytes
1999999,172999933
```

```rust
fn read_from_position() -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>> {
    let asset_pos = 172999933 as u64;

    let file_path = "assets.csv";

    let mut rdr = csv::ReaderBuilder::new()
        .flexible(true)
        .from_path(file_path)?;

    let mut wtr = csv::Writer::from_writer(io::stdout());

    let mut record = csv::ByteRecord::new();

    while rdr.read_byte_record(&mut record)? {
        
        let pos = &record.position().expect("position of record");

        if pos.byte() == asset_pos
        { 
            wtr.write_record(&record)?; 
            break;
        }     
    }

    wtr.flush()?;

    Ok(())
}
```

```bash
$ time ./target/release/testcsv
1999999,2015,10000,2016,10000,2017,10000,2018,10000,2019,10000,2020,10000,2021,10000,2022,10000,2023,10000,2024,10000,2025,10000,2026,10000,2027,10000,2028,10000,2029,10000

Time elapsed in readcsv() is: 239.290125ms

./target/release/testcsv  0.22s user 0.02s system 99% cpu 0.245 total
```

Comment: When timing program execution, did you compile in release mode?

Comment: Running `time` on `./target/_release_/testcsv` would suggest so yes. @Jmb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `from_path` you can use `from_reader` with a `File` and seek in that file before creating the `CsvReader`:

```rust
use std::{error::Error, fs, io::{self, Seek}};

fn read_from_position() -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>> {
    let asset_pos = 0x116 as u64; // offset to only record in example
    let file_path = "assets.csv";

    let mut f = fs::File::open(file_path)?;
    f.seek(io::SeekFrom::Start(asset_pos))?;
    let mut rdr = csv::ReaderBuilder::new()
        .flexible(true)
        // edit: as noted by @BurntSushi5 we have to disable headers here.
        .has_headers(false)
        .from_reader(f);

    let mut wtr = csv::Writer::from_writer(io::stdout());
    let mut record = csv::ByteRecord::new();

    rdr.read_byte_record(&mut record)?;
    wtr.write_record(&record)?;
    wtr.flush()?;
    Ok(())
}
```

Then the first record read will be the one you're looking for.

Comment: In your code, headers are enabled (as they are enabled by default), so this will assume the record at the offset is the header and then return the row after that one. You can either disable headers or use the [`csv::Reader::seek`](https://docs.rs/csv/latest/csv/struct.Reader.html#method.seek) method which will handle this for you. The benefit of `csv::Reader::seek` is that it provides the opportunity to set the correct position of the record.

Comment: See also: https://docs.rs/csv-index/latest/csv_index/

Comment: (base) padma@Padmas-MBP testcsv %  time ./target/release/testcsv
1000001,2015,10000,2016,10000,2017,10000,2018,10000,2019,10000,2020,10000,2021,10000,2022,10000,2023,10000,2024,10000,2025,10000,2026,10000,2027,10000,2028,10000,2029,10000

Time elapsed in read_from_position() is: 86.125µs

./target/release/testcsv  0.00s user 0.00s system 0% cpu 0.370 total
(base) padma@Padmas-MBP testcsv %